failure to start npx expo start
Set-ExecutionPolicy-Scope : The term 'Set-ExecutionPolicy-Scope' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2

Set-ExecutionPolicy-Scope Process-ExecutionPolicy Bypass

 + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-ExecutionPolicy-Scope:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException




to open a project for react native

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First check that you are running your project in the correct directory.
That means in vscode or any IDE that you are using just check the project path in the terminal and if it is wrong path adjust it by using cd or .. , Ig this will help you ;)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
